# Converting JSON String to Dictionary<String, Any> serializes Boolean as Int

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to serialize Json string into a dictionary
And it is converting the `boolean` value to a `int` value.
check out the code.

Check the output value for key "BoolArgument" its returning `1` instead of `true`

Note: I can not convert the string to a swift data object using Codable as the keys in the json dictionary are not constants.

````
========================
Code
========================

let inputArgumentsString = "{\"FloatArgument\":1.0,\"BoolArgument\":true,\"ObjectArgument\":{}}"

var toJson: Dictionary<String, Any>? {
     guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
     do {
         return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, Any>
     } catch let error {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
         return nil
     }
 }

print(self.inputArgumentsString?.toJson)```

========================
Output
========================

po self.inputArgumentsString?.toJson
▿ Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>
  ▿ some : 3 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : "BoolArgument"
      - value : 1
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : "ObjectArgument"
      - value : 0 elements
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : "FloatArgument"
      - value : 1
````

Comment: i guess you edited :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a debugger description of the result.

For `Bool` it uses `NSNumber` with values `1` as `true` and `0` as `false`.

If you call in your code something like:

```swift
guard let json = self.inputArgumentsString?.toJson,
        let boolean = json["BoolArgument"] as? Bool
        else { return }

print(boolean)
```

It will print `true` or `false`.

---

If you want to check if the value is a boolean or not, you could try using something like this:

```swift
for key, value in json {
  if let number = value as? NSNumber {
    let numberType = CFNumberGetType(number as CFNumberRef)

    switch numberType {
      case .charType:
        //Bool
        print(key, value as? Bool)
      case .sInt8Type, .sInt16Type, .sInt32Type, .sInt64Type, .shortType, .intType, .longType, .longLongType, .cfIndexType, .nsIntegerType:
        //Int
        print(key, value as? Int)
      case .float32Type, .float64Type, .floatType, .doubleType, .cgFloatType:
        //Double
        print(key, value as? Double)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question the keys in the json are not constant that can be anything. So in my case I have to make a check like `json[0].value is Bool` and In the case of my example it will return `true` even for `FloatArgument ` as its value is 1 too.

Comment: @Amey I've updated the answer check if that's what you need (only for numbers/booleans)

Comment: yeah that looks like it could work thanks!! I will try this and let you know

Comment: @Amey please take into account that code can be not compilable as I didn't test it, but it should give you an idea how to prepare it for your purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

Internally, `JSONSerialization` is an Objective-C class that uses `NSNumber` instances to represent both numeric and boolean values from JSON. When you print the dictionary, these instances have their numeric values printed. However, `NSNumber` knows when it's storing a boolean value, so it will automatically be bridged when you trying to access the value. `toJSON["BoolArgument"] as? Bool` should give the correct value.

In any event, using `Codable` to properly parse your types might be a better solution.